# Cannot install tidy html extension for php5 on mac os x leopard

Tags: php, installation, pecl, htmltidy

I'm trying to install pecl tidy extension for php5 on mac os x leopard.
I get tidy from

http://pecl.php.net/package/tidy

version 1.2

I run phpize, then configure and make command. On make command I obtain this error:
/usr/include/tidy/platform.h:530: error: duplicate ‘unsigned’

```
/usr/include/tidy/platform.h:530: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
/Users/paganotti/Desktop/tidyphp/tidy-1.2/tidy-1.2/tidy.c: In function ‘zm_info_tidy’:
/Users/paganotti/Desktop/tidyphp/tidy-1.2/tidy-1.2/tidy.c:387: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccUDFWws.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [tidy.lo] Error 1
```

How can I do install tidy php extension on mac os x leopard? Is there a tidy.so library already compiled so I only install without compile it?

Answer (score 0):

Get php5-tidy from macports for a version that will work on MacOSX.

You get macports from here: http://www.macports.org  and once installed you just do "port install php5-tidy"

Alternatively, you can use HomeBrew [Link](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: If I install macports, Does my current php5.3 version with extension remain or are all cleaned with a new installation?

Comment: It should be safe to have both, but you will have to make sure which version is used for what. Generally it is easier to use Macports or Homebrew for everything since it takes care of dependencies and updates down the road.